# SQL Server 2008: conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge, conflict

I have been looking for a solution for this for weeks now, and I am just gonna come out an ask. I have to merge two tables, but I cant rely on the id(pk) since it autoincrements and will most definitely never be the same. Here if my SP:

```
BEGIN
            MERGE dbo.Publication AS Target
            USING (SELECT id, parent_publication_id, name, date_created, last_updated
                    FROM dbo.ImportPublication
                    where id = @publicationid
                    )
            AS Source
            ON (Target.name = Source.name and Target.parent_publication_id = Source.    parent_publication_id)
            WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET 
                Target.name = Source.name, Target.parent_publication_id = Source.parent_publication_id, Target.date_created = Source.date_created, Target.last_updated = Source.last_updated
            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
            INSERT (name, parent_publication_id, date_created, last_updated )
            VALUES ( Source.name, Source.parent_publication_id, Source.date_created, Source.last_updated);
            DECLARE @pubId INT =  SCOPE_IDENTITY()
            if(@pubId != null or @pubId !='')
            begin
                UPDATE dbo.ImportFixedSize
                SET publication_id = @pubId
                where publication_id = @publicationId
            end
            else
                begin
                    set @pubId = ( select Id from Publication where name = ( select name from ImportPublication where id = @publicationid))
                    UPDATE dbo.ImportFixedSize
                    SET publication_id = @pubId
                    where publication_id = @publicationId
                end
```

I am getting the error in the heading. What could be the cause? I know for a fact the no two rows have the same name AND publication_group_id

Comment: what error message you get?

Comment: You might want to consider using an `OUTPUT` clause on that `MERGE` - you can use it to retrieve the identity value whether an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE` occurs, and it can cope with multiple rows as well (so you might be able to eliminate `id = @publicationid` in your `USING`, and I'm guessing eliminate the outer loop you've not shown)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the potential code smells that I can see that *could* be causing this - impossible  to know without seeing the exact point of failure.

1,

```
UPDATE SET 
            Target.name = Source.name, Target.parent_publication_id = Source.parent_publication_id
```

Why are you doing this? If it has matched then we don't attempt to change what it matched on.

2,

```
if(@pubId != null or @pubId !='')
```

When comparing for nulls you must use @value IS NULL or @value IS NOT NULL. Here is the proof:

```
    declare @test int = 1
if (@test != null)
    select 1
if (@test is null)
    select 2
if (@test is not null)
    select 3
```